# How to add product in the front-end?

Tags: magento-1.9, frontend

I added a link in customer account navigation, now I want to create grid and form in frontend for sellers to add products that have all attributes like Manage Products in the backend. How to do that? I'm new to Magento, please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Which magento version you have work on ?

Comment: @Swapan my magento version is 1.9.3

Comment: intended of creating a grid & form  to add products, you can create a role and assign that role to seller which will only create products. This will reduce your work

Answer (score 0):

Create a new block file via layout xml and call a phtml file. Then You put product collection in your new block file. Then call block function from phtml file.